# How to share location like whatsapp?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, share

I wanna share some fixed lat,long & text via `ACTION_SEND` using Intent. I can share url like              `String shareBody = "http://maps.google.com?q="+lat+","+lng;` & Image like

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName()
                        + "/drawable/" + "ic_launcher"));
sharingIntent.setType("image/*")
```

but i cant find the way which whatsapp using to share location. Is there any way to share location like whatsapp did? **OR**  pass some static image & by clicking on that image, map should be open in default chooser @ user side.Is there any way to implement that scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: try this https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=12,77

Comment: @appubala it shows only area on map.` maps.google.com/maps?q=12,77` shows area+location pin.

Comment: @BhoomikaBrahmbhatt Tare exactly su joie chie? person name get karvu che j server thi ave che e serialize thi ?

Comment: @BhoomikaBrahmbhatt you can make it custom

Answer (score 1):

there's an really awesome github project called [yowsup](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/) who reverse engineered whatsapp protocol. [here's](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/blob/a59ac410c057e8042c528e9f73e9f3eaada6e79e/yowsup/layers/protocol_media/protocolentities/message_media_location.py) the location sharing layer from it, you might find it handy

```
<message t="{{TIME_STAMP}}" from="{{CONTACT_JID}}" 
    offline="{{OFFLINE}}" type="text" id="{{MESSAGE_ID}}" notify="{{NOTIFY_NAME}}">
        <media 
            latitude="52.52393" 
            type="location"
            longitude="13.41747"
            name="Location Name"
            url="http://www.foursquare.com/XXXX"
            encoding="raw"
        >{{THUMBNAIL_RAWDATA}}</media>
    </message>
```